# Count occurences for all the variables inside a dataframe

Tags: pandas, count

I want to count the ocurrences of '?' values for all the variables in the 'adult' dataframe.

```
dataset.workclass[dataset.workclass == '?'].count()
```

gives me the number of occurences for 'workclass' column.

However, when I do:

```
for column in dataset:
    dataset.column[dataset.column == '?'].count()
```

Gives me the error:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'
```

Comment: dataset.colum**s**

Comment: add before and after example

Answer (score 0):

*count the ocurrences of '?' values for all the variables in the dataframe*. You can just compare and sum across the dataframe, no need to count for each column individually:

```
(dataset == '?').sum().sum()
```

---

*Example*:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x', '?'], 'B': ['?', 'y']})

dataset
   A  B
0  x  ?
1  ?  y

(dataset == '?').sum().sum()
2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know how many are in each of the columns

Comment: Then you only need one `sum`:  `(dataset == '?').sum()`